# MYSQL Displaying two columns from two different tables that's editable

Tags: mysql, where-clause, multiple-columns, multiple-tables, x-editable

I imagine this is pretty simple but I am still learning/teaching myself. I am trying to display a column from tableA and a column from tableB, neither have the same name. It also needs to be editable in the view panel(Navicate). This is what I have so far but I keep getting out of memory error. Both tables are completely different so there is no matching ID and no use for JOIN. Just need to display the value of Enabled in tableB.enabled where DAVID in tableA.name is found.

```
SELECT
   tableA.name AS Name,
   tableB.enabled AS Enabled
FROM
    tableA
    tableB
WHERE
   tableA.name  LIKE '%David%';
```

Comment: You are selecting the entire table b for each tuple of table a where the name like David. You should add some thing between a and b. Like a.id = b.id

Comment: also might I suggest this site to help you in your learning http://www.w3schools.com/sql/

Comment: There is no search criteria for tableB, I just need it to show the value of ENABLED if the select matches DAVID in tableA

Comment: I tried adding LIMIT 150 to the end and that just gave me the same result repeating 150 times.

Answer (score 0):

You need some sort of "tie in" between the data in the two tables. Here you are only searching through the rows in ableA for matches LIKE David. That still doesn't do any good for tableB where SQL has no idea what to look for in there.

A fix would be to do a join on the tables inside of the query tableA.id = tableB.id as suggested above.

Comment: There is no matching columns in both tables like id. The tables are completely different, I just need to show the value of enabled in tableB where name matches david in tableA

Comment: can I see your schema?